# Lock Screen Notifications Without Content?

Tags: iphone, notifications

Is there a way to have lock screen notifications which notify only that an activity has happened (SMS message, Facebook message, etc.) but doesn't show the *content* of that activity?  (I *suspect* there isn't, but thought I'd ask just to make sure.)

The idea behind this is that sometimes incoming messages contain personal or otherwise private information.  And while I'd like to have visible alerts that messages have arrived, I don't want that information displayed without being able to unlock the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for SMS/iMessage...

Settings > Notifications > Messages ... 'Show Previews'

That option doesn't exist for Facebook, though as I don't allow Facebook to push notify my phone I'm not sure what options there may be in the app itself.

Comment: Thanks!  I wonder if that's something Messages has customized or if the API exposes that and things like Facebook Messenger just don't take advantage of it (or at least not yet).  Seems like a useful feature.